# How to detect state start completion with a combination of $stateChangeStart, $stateChangeSuccess, $state with ui-router for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to impliment a loader image for each state change, and that will be apply to the whole page whenever the state changes. I tried to at least see if they exist, but somehow, I receive not definfed for $stateChangeStart for both when state change start and completed. I wonder what is the best way to do it? Because I want to put that $stateChangeStart as a var for ng-hide directive, so that when every time a state change starts, the loader will show, and (I assume) when $stateChangeSuccess is becoming defined, then its change of state is completed?

Please advice if anything of what I intent to do is wrong and better way to do it. Because I want to build the loader to be directive by itself and its reusable.

Below is the code I try to test these 3 objects.

```
app.run([          
  '$rootScope','$location','$state','$stateParams',/*'$templateCache',*/
function (

  $rootScope,   $location,  $state,  $stateParams/*,  $templateCache*/  ) {

    console.log("app run")
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("state start-------------------------")
        console.log($stateChangeStart,"$stateChangeStart ")
        console.log($stateChangeSuccess,"$stateChangeSuccess ")
        console.log($state);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("state $stateChangeSuccess-------------------------")
        console.log($stateChangeStart,"$stateChangeStart ")
        console.log($stateChangeSuccess,"$stateChangeSuccess ")
        console.log($state);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
app.run([          
  '$rootScope','$location','$state','$stateParams',/*'$templateCache',*/
function (

  $rootScope,   $location,  $state,  $stateParams/*,  $templateCache*/  ) {

    console.log("app run")
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $rootScope.showLoading = true;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $rootScope.showLoading = false;
    });
}]);
```

and then bind the `ng-show` to the `showLoading` property.

Comment: $scope is undefined is the error I received, and $scope can't be injected as dependency either... wonder how to fix them?

Comment: oops, do it on $rootScope.

Comment: hum... I did reference it this way <div ng-show='showLoading'> but the route change did not really load the effect though, seems the showLoading stay false all the time... Would you kindly create a fiddle if possible to demostrate it works? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/El86SQueLNPsvKtvj0A5?p=preview . If you open your dev console, you will see that on every state change, the showLoading property gets set and then cleared (start and success).

Comment: Wow.. interesting... ! Thanks a huge bunch!